# How to use nth-of-type with :before and targeting all but the last element, or the last element targeted differently

Tags: css, responsive-design, pseudo-element, pseudo-class

I'm using the css tricks responsive table (https://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/), but wondering how to get rid of the mobile-view's last td "before" content.

Basically for this code, which writes the text in the td's for the responsive view:

```
table td:nth-of-type(1)::before { content: "Expenses"; }
table td:nth-of-type(2)::before { content: "2015"; }
table td:nth-of-type(3)::before { content: "2016"; }
```

For the first line (which writes "Expenses" in the cell), how do I have that happen for all but the LAST cell? What's happening is my last  is the "totals" row for this table, so I don't need the "td content before" written to the last td (if that makes any sense... I'm also wondering if my table format needs tweaking, or I just have to deal with the "totals" line differently all together with these responsive tables -- there's no clear cut example on CSS tricks for a responsive table with a "totals" row).

I've been trying last-child, nth-last-of-type, etc. but having no luck. Here's an example of something I've tried:

```
 table td:nth-last-of-type(1)::before { content: " "; }
```

but, it does not work. I've read you can combine pseudo elements and psuedo classes... I've tried combinations with :not also, display: none, and have tried to change the HTML, but no luck. Maybe even write a display none with jQuery to the last td and add a class to then display none? I'm running in circles with this.

Can anyone help me?

thanks!

UPDATE: Here is a JSFiddle showing this: https://jsfiddle.net/gamehendgeVA/vh7bjscy/

Comment: I don't really understand the end goal. Can you post your markup too so we can see what you're working with?

Comment: you could maybe consider using a th cell (table header) instead of a td cell for items in the "totals" row, that might make it easier without all the extra work.

Comment: `tr > td:last-child:before {display:none;}` should work. If it isn't then something else is going on. Please reproduce your code in a snippet so we can figure out what is happening.

Comment: Hi Jeff - Very smart solution, and I just tried it... but, the problem then is that if I make them all th's, then the td's that I did need to be written (the 2015 and 2016) aren't there. And, if I make just the "Expense" a th and keep the others td's, then the mobile labels are "one off" then... but this is a great insight, thanks!

Comment: you might also consider doing a sample page at codepen with what you are working on, linked here.

Comment: fyi... I'm coming up with a fiddle now...

Comment: fiddle works too ;)

Comment: You can also include code samples here directly. In the editor view, click the `< >` icon

Comment: JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gamehendgeVA/vh7bjscy/

Comment: To be honest, for me it makes the most sense to simple change the first cell to "Year" https://jsfiddle.net/vh7bjscy/1/ (or leave it open entirely).

Comment: Hi Christoph - But, you read the table left to right when it's in the mobile view, so then it makes no sense.

Comment: Well, the mobile view destroys the typical table-2D relation anyways (No matter what you do, you will lose the information of just reading a single column). If you see the mobile view as table again then naming the first row year is actually more precise then calling it expense imo, because it re-establishes the connection between the rows and the columns.  Am I making sense?

Comment: I know what you mean, but then the table reads left to right ("expense" and then what the expense is) all the way down except at the bottom, which then reads down with a Year column. This seems more confusing, to me at least. Thanks for helping!

Comment: I'm starting to think maybe it's just me, haha, maybe having "Expense" on the left and then say "TOTAL EXPENSES" (caps and bold) reads ok (as it does for all the other td's)?

Comment: What I wanted to say is, that other than the table from the tutorial, your table is a "real 2D" table, because both your first row and your first column are descriptors (thus your very first data cell should strictly read "Expense \ Year"), and the payload actually starts in row:column 2:2. Thus the mobile view loses one information vector anyway. Semantically it then makes more sense to re-establish the table context by correctly naming the columns "Year" and "<expense>". But you are of course free to to what you want. If you stick for "expense" you can as well leave it for the last row.

Comment: How do you like: https://jsfiddle.net/vh7bjscy/2/ ?

Comment: Hi Christoph, it's a very interesting approach, but to me, it's strange that some of the cells read left to right, while others read down. I'll think on this. Again, very clever, but I just feel it's a bit confusing.

Comment: Semantically, really the `<td>Salaries</td>`, the "Publication costs", and the "Total Expenses" should be `<th scope="row">` while the existing `th`-es that you have would be `<th scope="col">`. That helps with [accessibility](https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/tables/two-headers/) and may present a different solution since, as @Christoph mentioned, yours is a "real 2D" table.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you just want to remove the last descriptor "Expense" for the "total expenses" row? For this, you have to specifically target the last row first, and then its first td:

```
table tr:last-of-type td:nth-of-type(1)::before{content: "";}
```

```css
table {border-collapse: collapse;width: 100%;color: #444;}
tr:nth-of-type(2n+1) {background: #eee none repeat scroll 0 0;}
th {background: #696969 none repeat scroll 0 0;color: #fff;font-weight: bold;}
td, th {border: 1px solid #ccc;padding: 6px;text-align: left; vertical-align: middle;}
/* responsive code */
@media
only screen and (max-width: 760px),
(min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)  {
    /* Force table to not be like tables anymore */
    table, thead, tbody, th, td, tr {
        display: block;
    }
    /* Hide table headers (but not display: none;, for accessibility) */
    thead tr {
        position: absolute; top: -9999px; left: -9999px;
    }
    tr { border: 1px solid #ccc; }
    td {
        /* Behave  like a "row" */
        border: none; border-bottom: 1px solid #eee; position: relative; padding-left: 50%;
    }
    td:before {
        /* Now like a table header */
        position: absolute;
        /* Top/left values mimic padding */
        top: 6px; left: 6px; width: 45%; padding-right: 10px; white-space: nowrap;
    }
    /* Grants and Contracts table */
    table td:nth-of-type(1)::before { content: "Expense"; }
    table td:nth-of-type(2)::before { content: "2014"; }
    table td:nth-of-type(3)::before { content: "2015"; }
    table td:nth-of-type(4)::before { content: "2016"; }

    table tr:last-of-type td:nth-of-type(1)::before {content: "";}
```

```html
<table id="expenses">
<thead>
<tr><th>Expense</th><th>2014</th><th>2015</th><th>2016</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td>Salaries</td><td>$85,256</td><td>$65,487</td><td>$94,626</td></tr>
<tr><td>Publication costs</td><td>22,698</td><td>69,548</td><td>66,555</td></tr>
<tr><td><strong>Total Expenses</strong></td><td><strong>$126,061</strong></td><td><strong>$169,013</strong></td><td><strong>$65,887</strong></td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

As discussed in the comments, I would personally prefer a [different labeling](https://jsfiddle.net/vh7bjscy/2/) because tables break with the usual ltr-reading paradigm, but that's of course up to your liking.

The optimal/correct formatting (in my humble opinion) of your table would be the following:

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
    color: #444;
}
tr:nth-of-type(2n+1) {
    background: #eee none repeat scroll 0 0;
}
th {
    background: #696969 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
}
th span{float:right}
td, th {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 6px;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
/* responsive code */
@media
only screen and (max-width: 760px),
(min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)  {
    /* Force table to not be like tables anymore */
    table, thead, tbody, th, td, tr {
        display: block;
    }
    /* Hide table headers (but not display: none;, for accessibility) */
    thead tr {
        position: absolute;
        top: -9999px;
        left: -9999px;
    }

    tr { border: 1px solid #ccc; }
    td {
        /* Behave  like a "row" */
        border: none;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
        position: relative;
        padding-left: 50%;
    }
    td:before {
        /* Now like a table header */
        position: absolute;
        /* Top/left values mimic padding */
        top: 6px;
        left: 6px;
        width: 45%;
        padding-right: 10px;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    /* Grants and Contracts table */
    table td:nth-of-type(1)::before { content: "2014"; }
    table td:nth-of-type(2)::before { content: "2015"; }
    table td:nth-of-type(3)::before { content: "2016"; }
```

```html
<table id="expenses">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Expense \ Year</th><th>2014</th><th>2015</th><th>2016</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<th>Salaries</th><td>$85,256</td><td>$65,487</td><td>$94,626</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Publication costs</th><td>22,698</td><td>69,548</td><td>66,555</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th><strong>Total Expenses</strong></th><td><strong>$126,061</strong></td><td><strong>$169,013</strong></td><td><strong>$65,887</strong></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Seems like Christoph seems to have a point about the wording of the cell headings, and as I understand the question looks like the right answer too.

Comment: I'm trying to implement this with the new renaming, but having formatting issues as the "real" values of the table (not just the edited JSFiddle) has longer elements in the td's like "Expense: Consulting costs/temporary costs/Miscellaneous costs" and then the "Expense: " part is on the second line of the cell, not at the beginning.. trying now to modify this: float:left;content: "Expense:";padding-right:5px; maybe with top-left or some clear:both?

Comment: Again, thanks so much for your help. I'm going to show these variations to my team tomorrow and see what they think. This code you provided did exactly what I was (originally) hoping for -- table tr:last-of-type td:nth-of-type(1)::before{content: "";} -- so, I marked this as the answer. I guess there are many ways to display these tables, both on desktop and mobile!

Comment: You are very welcome, for your last problem I came up with a quick solution which doesn't look too nice, but better than the first one when the line breaks: https://jsfiddle.net/vh7bjscy/5/

Comment: haha, nice! I was trying position absolute too, that's a cool use of "calc" :-) thanks again!

Comment: Feel free to upvote answers if you appreciate the effort and/or think an answer is good (this is generally spoken!) ;-)

Answer (score 0):

As you expected, you should be able to use

```
td:nth-last-child(1)::before {
    content: "";
}
```

or, more succinctly,

```
td:last-child::before {
    content: "";
}
```

This works in Chris Coyier's demo that accompanies the post you linked https://css-tricks.com/examples/ResponsiveTables/responsive.php (I added the styles in my browser inspector, and they worked). If it isn't working for you, you must have introduced some additional conflicting style. For example, in a two-`td` table, `table td:nth-child(2) {content: ...}` would override `td:nth-child(last) {content: ...}`

---

To label that row "total," simply change the content you use:

```
...
content: "Total";
...
```

Comment: Nice demo example, very interesting stuff

Comment: It's just the direct link to the demo that goes with the blog post the OP linked :)

Comment: ah so it is! :)

Comment: thank you henry, but still not working... Have you tried to change the https://jsfiddle.net/gamehendgeVA/vh7bjscy/ and get rid of the last "Expense" at the bottom? I'm starting to think the solution is in the way I'm formatting the table (HTML), since the mobile content before code doesn't seem to play well with "totals" rows (and I don't even want to get into rowspans and colspans, which was what I was trying to figure out yesterday with making this work responsively...)

Comment: In your fiddle, you can use both `td:nth-last-child(1)::before {content:...}` and  `td:last-child::before {content:...}` to change the pseudoelement content, see https://jsfiddle.net/enry/d4hv35Lw/. Sounds like maybe you're trying to hide the last line item? If so, target the `td` not the `td::before`, see https://jsfiddle.net/enry/t79uwsfu/

Comment: thanks, henry.. that seems to hide all of the 2016's though.

Comment: Yep! As Christoph figured out, you must have meant something like "for all but the LAST cell in the last row".  It'd be great if you updated your question to clarify 